# Should I trigger the default signal handler when I define my own handler?

Tags: java, signals

I'm trying to do some pre-shutdown cleanup when a `SIGINT` is sent to my Java application, using the [`sun.misc.Signal`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/sun/misc/NativeSignalHandler.java) and [`sun.misc.SignalHandler`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/sun/misc/SignalHandler.java) classes.

It appears when I register my handler the default behavior no longer occurs.  But there is a `SignalHandler.SIG_DFL` field containing "The default signal handler".  First of all, is the behavior of the default handler documented anywhere?  Secondly, should I prefer the following pattern when implementing my own handlers?

```
SignalHandler handler = new SignalHandler() {
    public void handle(Signal sig) {
      ... // handle SIGINT
      SignalHandler.SIG_DFL.handle(sig);
    }
};
```

**Edit:** I am aware the `sun.misc` package is not portable, and that shutdown hooks are the more robust way to deal with application termination.  Suffice to say I am aware of these features, and have a need to handle signals directly.  To my knowledge, `sun.misc.Signal` is the correct way to do this.

Comment: I'm not sure about how Java in particular handles signals, but I believe it is consistent with the UNIX programming environment; in that case you can see the default behavior for each signal in `man signal` (in Linux, this is in Section 7; Mac OS seems to have it in Section 3). You probably don't want to invoke the default handler for `SIGINT` unless you want to terminate (the default action for `SIGINT`).

Comment: In my testing, it appears the default handler kills (not interrupts) the `main` Java thread, leaving other non-daemon threads running.  But I'm hesitant to rely on my likely incomplete and/or flawed observations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As detailed in a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32190311/113632), you should *not* call `SignalHandler.SIG_DFL` in your `SignalHandler`, as you'll cause a `SEGV`.  In fact, the JVM doesn't use `SIG_DFL` either (for `INT`, `TERM`, and `HUP`).

[Under the covers](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/43cb25339b55/src/solaris/classes/java/lang/Terminator.java) all Java does when it receives any of those signals is call `System.exit()`.  So if you want to replicate the default behavior, simply call `System.exit()` yourself.  Obviously if you don't want to exit in response to the signal, there's no need to call the old/default signal handler at all.

**Warning:** this is undocumented behavior.  It's unlikely but entirely possible that future releases of Java could change this behavior.

Answer (score -1):

Answering your question: no you don't need (or want) to call default handler. But using this class is not portable.
You should install shutdown hook:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        //your graceful shutdown procedure here
    }
});
```

Comment: I understand the portability concern, but how to use shutdown hooks isn't  my question.