# How can I safely decorate an existing callback?

Tags: java, concurrency, callback

Suppose I'm working with the following callback API:

```
/**
 * Registers a new action which will be run at some later time on
 * some other thread, clearing any previously set callback action.
 *
 * @param callback an action to be run later.
 * @returns the previously registered action.
 */
public Runnable register(Runnable callback);
```

I'd like to register my own action, but I want to preserve any set behavior.  In other words I'd like my action to look something like:

```
new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    // do my work

    originalCallback.run();
  }
}
```

What's the cleanest way to provide `originalCallback` to my `Runnable`?

The naive solutions that come to mind risk introducing a window of time where `originalCallback` isn't available when the callback is called, or that involve some intricate locking.

Comment: When you say `the previously registered action`, do you mean `this` or `callback`?

Comment: Neither, it would be the `callback` passed to some previous call to `register()`.  Same as how `Map.put()` returns the previous value.

Comment: Why not create a private class that implements Runnable and provide originalCallback in the constructor?

Comment: At the time you construct the `Runnable` you don't have a reference to `originalCallback` yet - you get it by calling `register()`.

Comment: how about this - you register an empty callback, just to get the old callback. then you register the combined [new+old] callback.

Comment: That creates a race condition; if the callback triggers while the empty callback is set, nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*After some more digging I found Guava's [`SettableFuture`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/SettableFuture.html) and Java 8's [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html).  I'll leave my `BlockingSupplier` up for posterity, but either of these `Future` implementations would be more standard, and work just the same.*

---

You basically need a holder class with a blocking `get()` method.  Something like this:

```
public class BlockingSupplier<E> implements Supplier<E> {
  private final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
  private volatile E value;

  public synchronized void set(E value) {
    checkState(latch.getCount() > 0, "Cannot call set more than once.");
    this.value = value;
    latch.countDown();
  }

  @Override
  public E get() {
    latch.await(); // will block until set() is called
    return value;
  }
}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
BlockingSupplier<Runnable> supplier = new BlockingSupplier<>();
// Pass the BlockingSupplier to our callback
DecoratorCallback myAction = new DecoratorCallback(supplier);
// Register the callback, and set the BlockingSupplier to the old callback
supplier.set(register(myAction));
```

Where `DecoratorCallback`'s `run()` looks like this:

```
public void run() {
  // do my work

  // This will block until supplier.set() returns
  originalCallbackSupplier.get().run();
}
```

As durron597 mentions there are better ways to design a callback API, but given the API in the question, this seems reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

This is a terrible way to have an API. The [**Single Responsibility Principle**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) applies here. The way you are doing it now, your runnable is responsible for:

1. Whatever it's other job is
2. Calling the other callback.

You are breaking SRP inherently in your API design! Every class that uses this API is already broken from the getgo.

Fortunately, you can easily solve this problem with Guava's [`ListenableFuture`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained), which works like this:

1. Submit the task
2. Get [`ListenableFuture`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture.html) object back
3. Attach callbacks with [`Futures.addCallback`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#addCallback(com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture%2C%20com.google.common.util.concurrent.FutureCallback%2C%20java.util.concurrent.Executor))

Doing it this way ensures that your system puts the code for managing multithreading and happensBefore relationships in one place, and the code that actually does the work in another.

Comment: The callback API is out of my control.

Comment: @dimo414 Well that stinks. But this is why no one has thought of doing it your way before. I suppose your answer is an acceptable damage control solution.